# Why are my virtual hosts pointing to the first virtual host?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, lamp

I've been stuck with this problem for the past day now and whatever I do to try and fix it fails.

I am trying to migrate my sites from Windows IIS to Ubuntu LAMP. I have set them up in the var/www/ directory and made the config files for them.

I have set up 2 virtual hosts: 1 for samtownsendmusic.co.uk and 1 for [www.swim-4u.co.uk](http://www.swim-4u.co.uk)
(I thought it might be easier to just use the real domains instead of example ones.)

These are the config files:

```
    <VirtualHost samtownsendmusic.co.uk:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName samtownsendmusic.co.uk
        ServerAlias samtownsendmusic.co.uk
        ServerAdmin admin@samtownsendmusic.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/samtownsendmusic.co.uk


        RewriteEngine on

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =samtownsendmusic.co.uk
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

swim-4u.co.uk.conf

```
<VirtualHost www.swim-4u.co.uk:80>
            # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
            # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
            # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
            # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
            # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
            # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
            # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
            ServerName www.swim-4u.co.uk
            ServerAdmin admin@swim-4u.co.uk
            DocumentRoot /var/www/swim-4u.co.uk/
    
            RewriteEngine on
    
            # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
            # error, crit, alert, emerg.
            # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
            # modules, e.g.
            #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
            # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
            # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
            # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
            # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
            # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
            #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.swim-4u.co.uk
            RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>
```

I then go to samtownsendmusic.co.uk and it loads up fine.
When I try to go to [www.swim-4u.co.uk](http://www.swim-4u.co.uk) it just loads up samtownsendmusic.co.uk

I'm fairly new to apache and linux so any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Obviously have to ask, did you restart apache? Try `apachectl -S` or `httpd -S` and see if vhost is loaded. Are the VirtualHost blocks in the same conf file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did reload and restart apache. The httpd -S command says 'httpd: command not found'. The virutals hosts .confs are in their own separate files in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/[site-name].conf

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed it.
I'm not sure why it worked, but I removed my sites off cloudflare. I then reinstalled my SSL certificates, redid the Virtual hosts and deactivated all of my WordPress plugins.

Somehow, that made it work